# Strange behaviour on full stop (.) whilst in insert mode vim

Tags: vim

I am using vim with Pymode to write python source code. I have the come across some strange behaviour which is intermittent but very annoying.

If I am in insert mode and type a full stop (e.g. `self.method()`), whilst typing `self` vim prints at the bottom

`-- Keyword completion (^N^P) The only match`

As soon as I type the full stop vim seems to freeze momentarily, then 
`-- INSERT --` appears at the bottom, but my cursor is now *on* the full stop, so that when I write `method()` it actually appears behind the full stop. I keep having to go back and move the full stop.

I can't figure out when it happens and when it doesn't, when I open a new file it doesn't happen straight away.

Any ideas on what may be causing this? I have only noticed it recently.

Comment: check `:verbose :imap .` It is probably done by a plugin. So asked the plugin author

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt It's a pymode thing. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a problem caused by some combination of pymode and rope. Either way putting

`let g:pymode_rope_lookup_project = 0`

in your vimrc solves it apparently. See [here](https://github.com/klen/python-mode/issues/405) for the pymode issue.